# Opsworks - How to install gem from GitHub source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, aws-opsworks

While trying to create a new instance in Opworks it fails running the setup. The logs show that fails when try to install a gem from a Github source, I have tried several options:

```
gem 'themes_on_rails', git: 'git@github.com:yoolk/themes_on_rails.git', branch: 'master'
gem 'themes_on_rails', git: 'https://github.com/yoolk/themes_on_rails.git', branch: 'master'
gem 'themes_on_rails', github: 'yoolk/themes_on_rails', branch: 'master'
```

But the logs always show the same error:

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
An error occurred while installing themes_on_rails (0.3.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
```

How I need specify the gem in my Gemfile to get it working in Opsworks?

PD: It happen with all the gems that I specify from Github, not only with the example provided.

Comment: I tried to use `gem 'themes_on_rails', git: 'https://github.com/yoolk/themes_on_rails.git', branch: 'master'
` and it works fine.  Can you run bundle install successfully locally and inside the instance?

Comment: I have this issue too @darkcode. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your version of Bundler is up to date. This can be changed in the Layer Settings.